# Pyinstaller - multiple python scripts

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have two Python scripts which produces a GUI and runs code off some of the buttons. When run from Python, I run `mainImpactTool.py` which then runs `impactTool.py` to produce the GUI.

- `mainImpactTool.py`
- `impactTool.py`

I followed the guidance here:

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search

So I could create a single executable for running on Windows.

If I had one script I would normally run:

```
Pyinstaller --onefile mainImpactTool.py
```

However, to use two scripts, I did this:

```
Pyinstaller --onefile mainImpactTool.py impactTool.py
```

Pyinstaller works, but when I run the .exe file I get the error:

```
ImportError ... Failed to execute script mainImpactTool
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Just import the desired scripts into your projects with regular `import` and `pyInstaller` will take care of the  rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pyinstaller --onefile mainImpactTool.py
```

Try this it will work. Pyinstaller will recurse over all your imports(impactTool.py) and include it in the .exe.

Comment: I will give it a go now. I do not need to refer to the impactTool.py in the cmd?

Comment: @ScoutEU nope you don't need to

Comment: Great. Thank you!! Just building now. Will report back ASAP!

Comment: @ScoutEU Did it work ? and you have `impactTool.py` imported in the main file right ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have tried it with --onefile and without too. I have "from impactTool import impact" in my mainImpactTool.py file, so I believe it is imported. Plus it works fine from Pycharm

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. [8628] Failed to execute script mainImpactool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176574/discussion-between-agile-eagle-and-scouteu).

Comment: Any insights into the answer after the chat discussion above?

Comment: Hey going through the chat, unfortunately not. I can't recall how I fixed it, but I did. I'm very sorry